# re-authenticate and post redirect back to app fails OpenId Connect & IdentityServer4

Tags: identityserver4, openid-connect

If a user is doing a post operation and the the OpenId middleware decides to redirect for authentication (access token might have expired), IdentityServer after re-authentication directs to the post URL but without the original FormData causing my app to error. What is the recommended solution to this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I also put a message on the Identity Server GitHub page [here](https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4/issues/3515#issuecomment-518013174) and was answered by Brock Allen one of IdentityServer's creators:

"
This is not the responsibility of IdentityServer. That would be state your application needs to maintain across the OIDC protocol request.
"